# How to Apply pd.crosstab using Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply, crosstab

For the below pandas dataframe:

```
col = ["Q1", "Q2", "Cat"]
data = [ 
    ["Y","Y","BIN"], 
    ["Y","N","CIN"], 
    ["N","N","BIN"], 
    ["N","Y","CIN"], 
    ["Y","Y","BIN"] 
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
```

Output `df`:

```
Q1 Q2  Cat
0  Y  Y  BIN
1  Y  N  CIN
2  N  N  BIN
3  N  Y  CIN
4  Y  Y  BIN
```

I want to take crosstab "Cat" with "Q1 and Q2" in one go. For which I tried apply with lambda:

```
x = pandas.Series(["Q1", "Q2"])
a1 = x.apply(lambda a: pd.crosstab(df[a],df["Cat"]))
```

I am getting some weird results from this:

```
0    Cat  BIN  CIN
Q1           
N      1    1
Y   ...
1    Cat  BIN  CIN
Q2           
N      1    1
Y   ...
dtype: object
```

Whereas when I try the same using a for loop I am getting the below-desired result:

```
for i in x:
    a = pd.crosstab(df[i],df["Cat"])  
    print(a)
```

Desired output:

```
Cat  BIN  CIN
Q1           
N      1    1
Y      2    1
Cat  BIN  CIN
Q2           
N      1    1
Y      2    1
```

Please help me with the error happening in taking the Crosstab with apply + lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to use lambda with the crosstab

```
pd.crosstab([df.Q1, df.Q2], df.Cat)
```

Comment: Supplying multiple variables to "Index" in pd.crosstab results into a nested table. Q2 will get split in Q1.I am looking for outputs of q1 and q2 appended together, without nesting.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `melt`, then `pd.crosstab`:

```
df_melt = df.melt('Cat')
pd.crosstab([df_melt['variable'],df_melt['value']], df_melt['Cat'])
```

Output:

```
Cat             BIN  CIN
variable value          
Q1       N        1    1
         Y        2    1
Q2       N        1    1
         Y        2    1
```

For printing groups

```
df_out = pd.crosstab([df_melt['variable'],df_melt['value']], df_melt['Cat'])
for _, i in df_out.groupby(level=0):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
Cat             BIN  CIN
variable value          
Q1       N        1    1
         Y        2    1
Cat             BIN  CIN
variable value          
Q2       N        1    1
         Y        2    1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott. That's exactly I was looking for.